# Borrar un grafico de p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo un gráfico en p5.js que no tiene background, y está encima de un cavas. Por lo tanto, no puedo puedo poner `graphic.background(255)` porque taparía el canvas que tengo abajo.
Si pongo `graphic.clear()` solo borra la última capa, pero no borra el grafico entero.
¿Cómo podría borrar todo lo que hay pintado en `graphic`?

Comment: Has probado a repintar todo de nuevo?

Comment: Obviamente esa es una buena respuesta, y de hecho es la medida que he tomado, pero yo quiero saber si hay alguna manera de hacer un clear total, haciendo todo más sencillo para otros proyectos.